# How to verify that alert message is shown using Selenium in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I need to verify that in the web site, when fields are containing valid data, after clicking "Save" there is an alert shown that says that the "Information was saved successfully". For now I have a code to find the web element and fill the valid data like that:

```
IWebElement carName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("..."));
carName.Click();
carName.SendKeys("Name of the car");

IWebElement saveButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("..."));
saveButton.Click();
```

I want when the message is shown to be verified that it was shown and the test passed.

Comment: Is it a JS alert or an HTML alert that you need to dismiss? If you aren't sure, trigger the alert and then right-click on it. If you get nothing, it's probably a JS alert. If you get the usual context menu that includes "Inspect" then it's HTML. Update your question with this information. Where are your code attempts at accessing this alert message? What did you try? What error messages did you get, etc. Edit your question and add this information also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using webdriverwait as, depending on the form, there could be a delay before the success message.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("your xpath here")));
Assert.NotNull(element);
```

The assert format will differ based on your framework. That one is from xUnit.

Note: the package containing ExpectedConditions is not maintained, but they are pretty simple, and can be copied into your code, or own package, if you are worried about it.

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementIsVisible(By locator)
{
    return (driver) =>
    {
        try
        {
            return ElementIfVisible(driver.FindElement(locator));
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

private static IWebElement ElementIfVisible(IWebElement element)
{
    return element.Displayed ? element : null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I try the code 'ElementIsVisible' got red underlined and it says: " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ElementIsVisible' and no extension method 'ElementIsVisible' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?").

Comment: expectedconditions is contained in a separate nuget package. dotnetseleniumextras.waithelpers

Answer (score 1):

Identify if pop-up element appears or not, if not the element count will be 0

```
List<IWebElement> elementList = new List<IWebElement>();
elementList.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.XPath("..."));

if(elementList.Count > 0)
{
 //If the count is greater than 0 your element exists.
     Console.Write("pop up is present");
}else{
  Console.Write("pop up not present");
}
```

Note: Make sure to use `FindElements()` instead of `FindElement()`

Comment: @watchstars -you have removed my accept answer just now, any issue .. note that you can not accept the answer of all of them, you need to accept one which works for you

Comment: I though I can select both of them, because the both worked for me. What should I do now?

Comment: Select the one which is you are using and feeling that worked for you and the best answer among all